# HTML5 audio play function not work in iPad when called in setInterval()

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

```
                       setInterval('playSound()',2000);


                             function playSound(){

                                            var sound=new Audio('song.mp3');
                                                          sound.play();


                              }
```

This work in chrome but not work in ipad app.

Comment: This will not work iPad because it requires you to **click** something before audio/video can be played programmatically.

Comment: i have made a game in html5 canvas . i need it.now how do it.

Comment: Please fix your code: `setInterval(playSound, 2000);`!

Answer (score 4):

You cannot trigger play on audio or video elements programatically on iOS.
I once wrote a [blogpost](http://uxebu.com/blog/2011/11/29/state-of-html5-audio-in-ios-5/) about it.

> Sad, but true. [Apple deliberately decided](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH3-SW5) that a touch event is mandatory to load and play audio. There is no workaround for this.

There are three methods to circumvent this (at least somehow) all described in the post:

1. Bind touchstart event to body
2. Hot swapping sources
3. Use audio sprites

Of course you could also use PhoneGap/Cordova to wrap your App. There is a setting in the Cordova.plist called 'MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction'. Just set it to 'NO'.